# print_r($POST) not working but print_r($_SESSION) does?

Tags: php, session, post

Using a separate php file "session_info.php" navigated to in a new tab with the following code to view the $_SESSION array values and $_POST array values, only the $_SESSION array values show up.

```
session_start();
echo 'SESSION VALUES';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<br>';

echo 'POST VALUES';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

The print_r($_POST) only returns

```
Array
(
)
```

If I include a "print_r($_POST)" line in the php code that updates a database with the form's $_POSTed values and displays the values in a separate frame, the $_POST values show up in the frame O.K.
So why not in my "session_info.php" display?

Comment: If you are navigating directly to the page in a new tab, what exactly do you expect your `$_POST` values to be? You're not posting anything, why would they be anything other than empty?

Comment: Are you actually submitting POST data to the page displaying that? Without POST data, the `$_POST` is just an empty array

Comment: can you share the code from which $_POST  is getting it's value from

Comment: The form's posted input field values. The content of the $_POST array after the form has been submitted...

Comment: The code in your original post - is there a form on this page that you're submitting prior to returning `$_POST`? Or are you just going directly to a page with this code on it?

Comment: Tyler, I'm using the new tab, entering the url to the server where the session_info.php file is simply in an attempt to display what has been posted... No form, just the above code, but i forgot to show <?php ?>

Comment: @Skeeter — If you're just typing in the URL, then you are making a GET request. Why do you expect `$_POST` to have any data in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` values only show if you send a `POST` request to that page. If you open a new tab, you are sending a `GET` request, therefore your `$_POST` variable will be empty.

Your `$_SESSION` variable will show it's content on any type of request since it's unrelated to the type of request you send to get to the page.

---

Additionally, if you send binary data as a `$_POST` request, you'll have to read the raw posted data with `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: "if you send binary data" — JSON is is a text format, not a binary format.

Comment: Ok, so I would have to actually POST the values to the "session_info.php" page then...

Comment: Correct @skeeter, issue a "POST" request to session_info.php and you should see the data in $_POST

Comment: you are correct @Quentin, I was thinking about a recent issue with angular's $http, posting JSON and having to read the $_POST data from the raw php://input, similar to what I usually do with binary data. I edited the answer to avoid confusion. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: The point is that `$_POST` only gets populated for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` encoded form bodies. Everything else, of which binary data is only a subset, is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

When you open some page in browser, it runs request to server based on hostname and ip. It means that every request is new run of the script that you make. Every request has it's own data sent to server. For example if you make a form with `method="post"` you will send data to server with method post. And when server will process this request it will fill `$_POST` array with sended data.

If you send data via url (GET method) than your server will fill $_GET data with it. But if you just enter in address field your url there are no POST request at all and never will be. So your POST array is empty and it is OK for server.

In your case there are no error at all. I recommend you to read documentation on predefined variables in php again.